# How to set ImageView using Bitmap Array

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I'm doing one demo of getting Image URLs through `JSON` and after getting the `ULR` I'm downloading that images and display them into the `GridView`. For storing downloaded images I'm using `Bitmap` array and passing it to `ImageAdapter`. And now I want to display that images on next activity on `ImageView` for that I'm using following code in second activity..

```
        // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imageAdapter.bm[position]);
```

but It giving me error like `The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap)`. Please tell me how can I set the Image from `Bitmap` array to `ImageView`..

ImageAdapter Class:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public Bitmap bm[]=new Bitmap[4];
    ImageView imageView;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Bitmap[] bm){
        mContext = c;
        this.bm = bm; 
    }


    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bm.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return bm[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }



}
```

Main Class:

```
    public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    public static final  Bitmap bm[]=new Bitmap[4];
    public static  ImageAdapter img;
    public static  String[] imageurls;
    public static  GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);
        Log.d("LOG", "1");
        new GetImageUrls().execute();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        Log.d("LOG", "7");
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        Log.d("LOG", "8");
        img = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bm);
        Log.d("LOG", "9");
        gridView.setAdapter(img);
        Log.d("LOG", "10");


        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Log.d("LOG", "11");
                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                Log.d("LOG", "12");
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GetImageUrls  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        Context context;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        // URL to get JSON
        private static final String url= "http://xxx.x.xxx/demo/test.json";
        private static final String MAIN = "mainCategory";
        private static final String IMAGE = "mcatimage";
        // JSONArray
        JSONArray loginjsonarray=null;
        //result from url

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("LOG", "2");
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            //pDialog.show();
            Log.d("LOG", "3");
        }
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
            Log.d("LOG", "4");
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            Log.d("LOG", "5");
             // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonstr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST, null);
            Log.d("Response: ", ">"+jsonstr);
            if(jsonstr!=null)
            {
                try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj =new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                        loginjsonarray=jsonObj.getJSONArray(MAIN);
                        imageurls=new String[loginjsonarray.length()];
                        for(int i=0;i<loginjsonarray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject l=loginjsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            imageurls[i]=l.getString(IMAGE);
                            Log.d("imageurls: ", imageurls[i]);
                        }
                        for(int i=0;i<imageurls.length;i++)
                        {   
                            bm[i]=DownloadImage(imageurls[i]);
                            Log.d("LOG", bm[i].toString());
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"Check your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }


        public Bitmap DownloadImage(String STRURL) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream in = null;       
            try {
                    int response = -1;
                    URL url = new URL(STRURL);
                    Log.d("DownloadImage: ", url.toString());
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))             
                        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                    try{
                        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        httpConn.connect();
                        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();  
                        Log.d("DownloadImage response: ", Integer.toString(response));
                        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                            Log.d("DownloadImage: ", in.toString());
                        }                    
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new IOException("Error connecting"); 
                    }
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    Log.d("DownloadImage Bitmap: ", bitmap.toString());
                    in.close();
                }catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            Log.d("LOG", "6");
            return bitmap; 
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

FullActivity Class:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    Log.d("Position", Integer.toString(position));
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.bm[position]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its so simple way use [setImageBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)..

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.bm[position]);
```

Comment: Error gone but image is not displayed on next activity

Comment: any error at runtime ? or may be you have blank bitmap

Comment: Check whether image null or not?

Comment: NO error is coming,,And the images are also downloaded..and in second activity at Log the image position is also coming correctly..:(

Comment: @Aksh CAn you show your Bitmap array initialization?

Answer (score 1):

You should use , **setImageBitmap (Bitmap bm)** method which Sets a Bitmap as the content of this ImageView.

So your code will be,

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.bm[position]);
```

[Docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

Comment: Error gone but image is not displayed on next activity

Comment: Try imageView.setImageBitmap(getItem[position]); and post your FullImageActivity class as well.

Comment: I added the FullActivity Class,,please check.

Comment: Add a log in the getView() method of ImageAdapter and see if control reaches there. I think it is not getting executed. Let me  know?

Comment: Hey I set log at every line,,,getView() executing successfully..:(

Comment: The NPE exception you are getting is at this line. 
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.bm[position]) due to 
imageAdapter.bm[position]. Hard code it with an image and see if it works. If yes we will know the issue and will try to solve this

Comment: The issue is solved,,I was accessing the ImageAdapter's Bitmap Array and the Images were in AndroidGridLayoutActivity's Bitmap Array..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49136/discussion-between-atul-o-holic-and-aksh)

Answer (score 1):

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.bm[position]);
```

Comment: ,,,The Error is gone But Image is not displayed on next activity

Comment: if u set the image on current activity then how can u see this in next activity dude what u want to say i cant understand

Answer (score 0):

here i give you my code of my app that works with a gallery from drawable resources with int position, modify it for your needs, should work with your code.

My intent of gallery is:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View  view, int position, long id) {
    int selectedId = imgs[position]; 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery3DActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("imageId", selectedId);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the main activity i receive the intent and set it on the imageview:

```
Intent avatar = getIntent(); 
int imageId = avatar.getIntExtra("imageId", -0); 
// -0 would be a default value
// -1 will crash with a missing resource

if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    Avatar.setImageResource(imageId);
    savedAvatar.setImageResource(imageId);
} else {
    Avatar.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
}
```

Your code is similiar as mine, but you get it from url them to bitmap, me i get it from drawable resources, with long id list set on the activity java for name and position, i chose the one i want to set as avatar them pass it inside intent to main activity and define the intent name that contains the drawable cache to an imageview, after in button onclick i convert to bitmap, bitmap to string, string to image to restore imageview view on start main activity, and i save the string to sharedpreferences, getting the imageview view back again even after close the app.

Good luck