# How do I set a bitmap to an imageview where the bitmap is stored in a bitmap list

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I have a bitmap list which i want to set the first item to an imageview. I have tried this so far:

```
        ivHeader.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.BitmapList.toArray()[1]);
```

However, multiple errors are being thrown and it does not look like my approach is correct. In other questions i have seen that image adapters have been created which they then use to set the bitmap. However, i am here to see if my approach is correct or if there is a slightly similar method which does not involve me producing an image adapter.

Similar question that uses image adapter: [How to set ImageView using Bitmap Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217690/how-to-set-imageview-using-bitmap-array)

**Setting bitmaps to bitmap list in getArticle class:**

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap> BitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


   Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                for(int x = 1; x < 6; x++){
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(json.getString("Picture" + x + "URL")).getContent());
                BitmapList.add(bitmap);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Setting bitmap to imageview in activity:**

```
    ivHeader = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivHeader);


    getArticle data = getArticle.getMyData();

    ivHeader.setImageBitmap(data.BitmapList.get(1));
```

Comment: You should use `get(1)` rather than converting the whole list to an array.

Comment: Also, what errors do you get?

Comment: So like: ivHeader.setImageBitmap(data.BitmapList.get(1));

Comment: The error i am getting is that: "BitmapList cannot be resolved or is not a field" for "BitmapList". However BitmapList is able to be retrieved.

Comment: What is the declaration for `data`?

Comment: @GiruBhai This is clearly a compiler error, not a runtime one.

Comment: decleration:   getArticle data = getArticle.getMyData();

Comment: Please edit your question with some code so that we can see the context of the line that causes the error. It appears that you have more than one error and they are all closely related. In particular, you should include all declarations and other code that is needed to reproduce the exact same errors that you get.

Comment: Edited original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that

```
ivHeader.setImageBitmap(BitmapList.get(1));
```

is what you want here.

Two other suggestions:

1. Change `BitmapList` to `bitmapList`. It is traditional to start variable names with lower case.
2. `getArticle data = getArticle.getMyData();` looks wrong. You are trying to use `getArticle` as both a class name and as a variable name. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, so I don't have any specific suggestions. To start, though, you need to learn the difference between a class and a reference.

Comment: Thanks, it was due to the naming.

Comment: @jamesgates1 I fixed an error in my original answer.